# socket.io javascript don't work

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Anybody an idea why this doesn't work ?

```js
function startServer() {
    console.log('function start');
    var keyBool = false;
    var client = require('socket.io').listen(3000).sockets;
    
    client.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('someone connected');
        
        socket.on('party', function (party) {
            console.log(party);
            console.log('testbla');
        });

    });
}
```

the client side:

```js
function client() {
    var party = 'test';
    var server = "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
    try {
        var socket = io.connect(server);
    } catch (e) {
        alert('failed to connect');
    }
    //setInterval(function () { sendCoordinates }, 125);
    //setInterval(function () { sendParty }, 5000);
    if (socket !== undefined) {
        alert('ok');
        try {
            socket.emit('party', {
                party: 'test'
            });
            alert('sended...');
        } catch (e) {
            alert('failed with reason: ' + e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the server and client logs 'someone connected', but not the party object I send...
Client is an chrome extension and the server a node.js 'file'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using some of that code is needed, other than that have you port forwarded?

```js
            if (socket !== undefined) {
                alert('ok');
                try {
```

Comment: i'm maybe interested in developing a a bot, but i already have one. There's a tiny problem: the communication between the node.js and the extension, everything else is working fine.

Comment: Would you like to work together on your project? As I am also making the same type of bot.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
$ node server.js 
function start
someone connected
{ party: 'test' }
testbla
```

Maybe you expect the object to be sent before 'ok' is pressed on `alert('sended...');`..? 
`alert()` is not the best option for debug.

---

```
$ node -v
v5.3.0
```

`"socket.io": "^1.3.7"`